# Value '0' (Zero) not getting updated in Postgres database when updation is performed using database query written using go-gorm

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm, go-gin

I'm trying to update an existing record in PostgreSQL database. I have a column which accepts integers. I have tried doing the update using db query written in gorm. All the integers are getting updated except `0` (zero).

Can anyone help me fix this issue?

```
type RoleTypes struct {
    ID       int `gorm:"primary_key,AUTO_INCREMENT"`
    RoleName string
    IsEnable int
}
```

Below is the db query:

```
func UpdateRoles(db *gorm.DB, r *models.RoleTypes) (err error) {
    Logr.Debug("Inside UpdateRoles method")

    if err = db.Debug().Model(&r).Where("ID=?", r.ID).Update(&r).Error; err != nil {
        Logr.Error("error occured!!", zap.Any("Error", err))
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

I'm trying to Update the `IsEnable` to `0` (Zero).

Comment: Maybe `IsEnable` is actually a `boolean` in the database? (and if not: why not? a `boolean` would be the natural choice for a true/false flag)

Comment: IsEnable is an int in db as well. Yeah boolean does the work but im using 0 and 1 globally. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Maybe try the tag `gorm:"default:0"`. (http://doc.gorm.io/crud.html#default-values) *"NOTE all fields having zero value, like 0, '', false or other zero values won't be saved into database but will use its default value, it you want to avoid this, consider to use pointer type or scaner/valuer"*

Comment: ... or use a map (http://doc.gorm.io/crud.html#update) *"Update with struct only works with none zero values, or use map[string]interface{}"*.

Comment: @mkopriva Using a map[string]interface{} works fine when i am updating all the fields in the struct. But when im updating only "IsEnable" field the remaining fields are updated as blank(existing values are getting erased).

Comment: Did you try with the `Updates` method, as opposed to `Update`? *"Update multiple attributes with `map`, will only update those changed fields"* taken from here: http://doc.gorm.io/crud.html#update-changed-fields

Comment: Yeah i have tried with Updates as shown in the link, its the same result.

Comment: when update with struct, GORM will only update those non zero value fields, check the  `Update Selected Fields` section here: http://doc.gorm.io/crud.html#update